# Connect VM Behind pfsense interface to host on physical home router

Tags: pfsense

I have a Hyper-V server (192.168.1.251) on my home network. My home router is 192.168.1.1. I have a PFSense VM with a bridged network adapter (192.168.1.177)

I have a couple of interfaces connected to the PFSense VM and the hosts on all those interfaces have internet connectivity.

Interface I am having issues with is Opt2 (10.0.0.1/8). It has internet connectivity, and I can ping my the Opt2 address and my other gateways (10.0.0.1, 192.168.1.177 and 192.168.1.1).

What I want to do, is reach 192.168.1.251 from a host on the Opt2 interface (10.0.0.0/8 network)...

I have no idea how to do this and I am not really sure why it's not working right now.

Anyone have any ideas how I can do this? Please see my network diagram for clarity...

[network diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByHIZ.jpg)

(the red line represents the connection I want to make, but cant... I want to enable RDP 3389)

Comment: the guacamole server is a guest VM of the hyper-v host, isn't it? Just for clarity.

Comment: Yes the pfsense and the guacamole servers are both VMs of the Hyper-V host

Answer (score 0):

(if I understand well) You can achieve your goal using two different methods: 
1. One can be using a NAT rule in the pfSense that translates the connection.
2. The second could be creating a vswitch (internal is a good choice) in the Hyper-V server and connect a network adapter in the guacamole server to that vswitch.

Hope that can provide a orientation on what you can do.

Update: Since you're using Windows Server 2016 Hyper-V, you can create a NAT network following this [MS documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/setup-nat-network), with this configuration you can communicate VMs to the outside world and vice versa. Just create an internal vSwitch, then create the NAT network using the vSwitch created and connect VMs to the vSwitch. I don't explain the NAT rule creation using pfSense because (in my opinion) is more complex to troubleshoot when the NAT rules are not working.

Comment: I tried making a NAT rule but I couldn't figure out how to get it working... I didn't think of adding a secondary network interface but that is a good idea and I think I could get that working...

Comment: Go ahead and give it a try. Don't forget to upvote or mark as an answer if it was helpful for you.

Comment: I thought about it actually and I don't think I can connect a physical host to a hyper-v internal switch and the VM on that internal switch?

Comment: What version of Hyper-V/Windows Server you've got?

Comment: I am using Windows Server 2016 1607 Standard Edition

Comment: Updated my answer to provide a similar/alternative solution. Let me know if you need more help.